# How to augment multiple XML child elements Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a use case where I need to take an existing XML document and augment it from a database, for an integration process.

I'm starting with something like:

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <data>A</data>
  </child>
  <child>
    <data>B</data>
  </child>
  <parentData>
    <data/>
  </parentData>
</parent>
```

What I am trying to do is add a `<moreData .../>` tree to each of the `child` elements.

I could just write a custom bean that does everything, but that doesn't feel the right approach. I've considered using a splitter based on the xpath for child, followed by a content-enricher, which will allow me to fetch the additional data, but I can't see how to reassemble everything afterwards.

At the moment, I'm thinking I need to use a loop, but that feels clunky too, and will require a custom aggregation strategy for the content-enricher.

```
from("direct:a")
  .loop().xpath("count( parent/child )", Integer.class )
  .setHeader("Key")
  .xpath( "parent/child[function:properties('CamelLoopIndex')]/data", String.class )
  .enrich("sql:SELECT xmldata FROM dataTable WHERE key = :#Key?dataSource=myDS",
     new MyCustomAggregationStrategy() )
```

This must be an everyday occurrence in the world of Camel but I can't find any examples of how to do it.

If I were doing this in a custom bean, I'd get an xpath for the `child` element, then iterate through the nodeset performing the query and attaching the result as a new child to node. I just can't see how to do this "nicely" in Camel.

Any ideas or hints would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Is parent xml big size ?

Comment: Whole document is about 150k, but may be bigger with real data. Not likely to exceed 10M. Key is from child data xpath in the setHeader.

Comment: Hi, i found better way to augment xml in splitter. My old answer looks too bulky, so try my new answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704380/aggregate-with-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

You can try prepare map of new nodes , and then transform parent xml with xslt and get prepared new nodes using java inside xsl. Here some example. Route:

```
 @Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
from("timer://foo?period=30s")
            .setBody(constant("<parent>\n" +
                    "  <child>\n" +
                    "    <data>A</data>\n" +
                    "  </child>\n" +
                    "  <child>\n" +
                    "    <data>B</data>\n" +
                    "  </child>\n" +
                    "  <parentData>\n" +
                    "    <data/>\n" +
                    "  </parentData>\n" +
                    "</parent>"))
            .convertBodyTo(org.w3c.dom.Document.class)
            .setProperty("oldBody", simple("body"))

            .split(xpath("//child"), (oldExchange, newExchange) -> {
                Map<String, String> map = oldExchange != null ? oldExchange.getProperty("map", Map.class) : new HashMap<>();
                map.put(newExchange.getIn().getHeader("Key", String.class), newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                newExchange.setProperty("map", map);
                return newExchange;
            })
            .setHeader("Key", xpath("//data/text()"))
//                .to("sql:SELECT xmldata FROM dataTable WHERE key = :#Key?dataSource=#myDS")
            //emulate result of your sql
            .process(exchange -> {
                exchange.getIn().setBody("<someNewData>".concat(exchange.getIn().getHeader("Key", String.class).concat("Result")).concat("</someNewData>"));
            })
            .end()
            .setBody(exchangeProperty("oldBody"))
            .to("xslt:xslt/result.xsl?transformerFactory=#nsTF")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Body:${body}");}

public static String getElement(Object map, String key) {
    return (String) ((Map) map).get(key);
}
```

nsTF is bean of class:

```
public class NonSecureTransfomerFactory extends TransformerFactoryImpl {
@Override
//for using java inside xsl
public boolean isSecureProcessing()
{
    return false;
}
}
```

xslt stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:getter="my.package.RouteHelper">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements='*'/>

<xsl:param name="map"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="key" select="data/text()"/>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"     select="getter:getElement($map,$key)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Output xml:

```
<parent>
<child>
    <someNewData>AResult</someNewData>
    <data>A</data>
</child>
<child>
    <someNewData>BResult</someNewData>
    <data>B</data>
</child>
<parentData>
    <data/>
</parentData>
</parent>
```

Comment: Or you can instead of collecting map of new nodes concat all child nodes (with new parts) and then apply it instead of all old child nodes. This way will remove calling java inside xsl but oblige keep in memory all new child nodes.